# Is there a way to place recurring code into a function to be called by multiple subs in VBA

Tags: vba, function, excel, subroutine

I have a bunch of subs for different categories in a table I'm building in excel. Each sub has its' own data it pulls from various flat files, but it all has the same ending which is placing each value into a specific cell based on the category header it aligns to in the row and column. So, all that is different is the if statement at the beginning. Is there a way to put this block of code in a separate sub or function or something and have just one call to it in each other sub so that I don't have to constantly type it out/ if I want to change it I would only have to change it in one place? Here is an example of the code:

This part is at the beginning of each sub and changes based on the row header

```
Sub calccategory()

    For k = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(k, 4) = "row 1" Then
```

This part is the part I want to place in a function or sub because it will be the same every time

```
            Dim CWS As Worksheet
            Workbooks(ThisBook).Activate

            For j = 5 To 15

                For g = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

                    If Cells(3, g) = "col1" Then

                        With Range(Cells(k, j * 4 + 2), Cells(k + 1, j * 4 + 4))
                            On Error Resume Next
                            CWS.Cells(k, g).Value = col1_n
                        End With

                    ElseIf Cells(3, g) = "col2" Then

                        With Range(Cells(k, j * 4 + 2), Cells(k + 1, j * 4 + 4))
                            On Error Resume Next
                            CWS.Cells(k, g).Value = col2_n
                        End With

                    ElseIf Cells(3, g) = "col3" Then

                        With Range(Cells(k, j * 4 + 2), Cells(k + 1, j * 4 + 4))
                            On Error Resume Next
                            CWS.Cells(k, g).Value = col3_n
                        End With

                    ElseIf Cells(3, g) = "col 4" Then

                        With Range(Cells(k, j * 4 + 2), Cells(k + 1, j * 4 + 4))
                            On Error Resume Next
                            CWS.Cells(k, g).Value = col4_n
                        End With

                    ElseIf Cells(3, g) = "col5" Then

                        With Range(Cells(k, j * 4 + 2), Cells(k + 1, j * 4 + 4))
                            On Error Resume Next
                            CWS.Cells(k, g).Value = col5_n
                        End With

                    End If

                Next g

                On Error GoTo 0

            Next j
```

This part would again me part of the end of each sub and not a part of this function I want

```
        End If

    Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: Does that code block, that you want in a separate function, need any inputs? Why couldn't you just put that in it's own sub, then call that sub from your main function?

Comment: ive tried that - if I do that, I have to put in the other letter variables like k and j for loops which defeats the purpose and also it doesn't map to the right row

Comment: What's the `If Cells(k,4) = row 1"`?? Do you mean if the row that `Cells(k,4)` is on is row 1?

Comment: Look into [passing arguments to Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263527(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: you'd really add some more info about what your code is supposed to do. there are many _strange_ things, the weirdest being that `With Range(Cells(k, j * 4 + 2), Cells(k + 1, j * 4 + 4))` reference that isn't exploited at all since no statement within the next `End With` has any dot (.) ... Anyhow I'll add an answer for what I could grasp of it

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do, as I posted in a comment, is pass the arguments to the new sub.  Also, you have lots of recurring code, so I tried to tighten that up.

```
Sub calccategory()
For k = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(k, 4) = "row 1" Then
        theLoop k
    End If
Next k
End Sub
```

```
Sub theLoop(ByVal k As Integer)
Dim CWS     As Worksheet

Set CWS = Workbooks(ThisBook)

For j = 5 To 15
    With CWS
        For g = 1 To .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            With .Range(.Cells(k, j * 4 + 2), .Cells(k + 1, j * 4 + 4))
                On Error Resume Next
                If .Cells(3, g) = "col1" Then .Cells(k, g).Value = col1_n
                    ElseIf .Cells(3, g) = "col2" Then .Cells(k, g).Value = col2_n
                    ElseIf .Cells(3, g) = "col3" Then .Cells(k, g).Value = col3_n
                    ElseIf .Cells(3, g) = "col 4" Then .Cells(k, g).Value = col4_n
                    ElseIf .Cells(3, g) = "col5" Then .Cells(k, g).Value = col5_n
            End If
        End With
    Next g
End With                     'CWS
On Error GoTo 0
Next j
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should do something like this...

```
Option Explicit


Public Sub CalCategoryInternal(ByVal str_col2 As String, _
                             ByVal g As Long, _
                             ByVal k As Long, _
                             ByVal j As Long, _
                             ByRef CWS As Worksheet)


        With Range(Cells(k, j * 4 + 2), Cells(k + 1, j * 4 + 4))
            On Error Resume Next

            CWS.Cells(k, g).Value = str_col2

            On Error GoTo 0

        End With

    End Sub

Sub calccategory()

    Dim k, ThisBook, j, g, col1_n, col2_n, col3_n, col4_n, col5_n


    For k = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(k, 4) = "row 1" Then

            Dim CWS As Worksheet

            Workbooks(ThisBook).Activate

            For j = 5 To 15

                For g = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                    If Cells(3, g) = "col1" Then

                        Call CalCategoryInternal("col1", g, k, j, CWS)
'                        With Range(Cells(k, j * 4 + 2), Cells(k + 1, j * 4 + 4))
'                            On Error Resume Next
'                            CWS.Cells(k, g).Value = col1_n
'                        End With

                    ElseIf Cells(3, g) = "col2" Then
                        Call CalCategoryInternal("col1", g, k, j, CWS)
                        With Range(Cells(k, j * 4 + 2), Cells(k + 1, j * 4 + 4))
                            On Error Resume Next
                            CWS.Cells(k, g).Value = col2_n
                        End With

                    ElseIf Cells(3, g) = "col3" Then
                        With Range(Cells(k, j * 4 + 2), Cells(k + 1, j * 4 + 4))
                            On Error Resume Next
                            CWS.Cells(k, g).Value = col3_n
                        End With

                    ElseIf Cells(3, g) = "col 4" Then
                        With Range(Cells(k, j * 4 + 2), Cells(k + 1, j * 4 + 4))
                            On Error Resume Next
                            CWS.Cells(k, g).Value = col4_n
                        End With

                    ElseIf Cells(3, g) = "col5" Then
                        With Range(Cells(k, j * 4 + 2), Cells(k + 1, j * 4 + 4))
                            On Error Resume Next
                            CWS.Cells(k, g).Value = col5_n
                        End With

                    End If

                Next g

                On Error GoTo 0
            Next j
        End If
    Next k


End Sub
```

Beware - this is really a low quality code. E.g. the "Dim"s on the top should not be declared this way and you can improve it further a lot. I do not see where you set the worksheet, thus I suppose that this is just a small part of the code. Enjoy it!

Answer (score 0):

yeah you can easily stick that in its own sub, and you can pass K into it as an argument by value, that would just look like this:

```
Sub calccategory()

For k = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
  If Cells(k, 4) = row 1" Then
    Call newSub(k)
  End If
 Next k
 End Sub

Sub newSub(byval k as long)
Dim CWS As Worksheet

Workbooks(ThisBook).Activate  

For j = 5 To 15

For g = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  If Cells(3, g) = "col1" Then

With Range(Cells(k, j * 4 + 2), Cells(k + 1, j * 4 + 4))
 On Error Resume Next    
CWS.Cells(k, g).Value = col1_n    
End With

 ElseIf Cells(3, g) = "col2" Then    
    With Range(Cells(k, j * 4 + 2), Cells(k + 1, j * 4 + 4))
     On Error Resume Next  
   CWS.Cells(k, g).Value = col2_n
 End With

ElseIf Cells(3, g) = "col3" Then    
    With Range(Cells(k, j * 4 + 2), Cells(k + 1, j * 4 + 4))
     On Error Resume Next    
   CWS.Cells(k, g).Value = col3_n    
End With

ElseIf Cells(3, g) = "col 4" Then
With Range(Cells(k, j * 4 + 2), Cells(k + 1, j * 4 + 4))
     On Error Resume Next      
   CWS.Cells(k, g).Value = col4_n    
End With

ElseIf Cells(3, g) = "col5" Then
With Range(Cells(k, j * 4 + 2), Cells(k + 1, j * 4 + 4))
     On Error Resume Next     
CWS.Cells(k, g).Value = col5_n
End With    

End If

Next g


  On Error GoTo 0
  Next j

end sub
```

you might also consider using a select statement and nesting your select statement in your with range..  although it doesn't look like you're actually referencing your with statement so you can probably get rid of it.

I'd wonder where you're getting variables "ThisBook" "col1_n" / "col2_n" ... cause you might run into a "function or variable not defined" issue unless you define them either module wide or pass them in as arguments into the function.

You're also not defining CWS equal to anything so you might get an object required error.  which is what I assume the on error resume next statements are about.

So some of the improvements might look similar to this:

```
Sub calccategory()

    For k = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(k, 4) = "row 1" Then
            Call newSub(k)
        End If
    Next k

End Sub
Sub newSub(ByVal k As Long)
Dim CWS As Worksheet
Set CWS = Workbooks(ThisBook).Sheets("mySheetName")

For j = 5 To 15
    On Error Resume Next
    For g = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If Cells(3, g) = "col1" Then
            With Range(Cells(k, j * 4 + 2), Cells(k + 1, j * 4 + 4))        'still unused
                CWS.Cells(k, g).Value = col1_n
                Select Case Cells(3, g)
                    Case "col2"
                        CWS.Cells(k, g).Value = col2_n
                    Case "col3"
                        CWS.Cells(k, g).Value = col3_n
                    Case "col 4"
                        CWS.Cells(k, g).Value = col4_n
                    Case "col5"
                        CWS.Cells(k, g).Value = col5_n
                End Select
            End With
        End If
    Next g
    On Error GoTo 0
Next j
End Sub
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

meanwhile you're adding more info, I can throw in what follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub calccategory()
    Dim k As Long
    Dim CWS As Worksheet
    Dim col1_n As Variant, col2_n As Variant, col3_n As Variant, col4_n As Variant, col5_n As Variant

    With ActiveSheet
        For k = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
            If .Cells(k, 4) = "row 1" Then FillValues k, Workbooks("ThisBook").ActiveSheet, CWS, Array(col1_n, col2_n, col3_n, col4_n, col5_n)
        Next k
    End With

End Sub

Sub FillValues(k As Long, ws As Worksheet, CWS As Worksheet, colArray As Variant)
    Dim j As Long, G As Long, col As Long
    Dim strng As String

    With ws
'        For j = 5 To 15 '<--| I commented it since it seems not to be used anywhere, once removing that 'With Range(Cells(k, j * 4 + 2), Cells(k + 1, j * 4 + 4))'
            For G = 1 To .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                strng = .Cells(3, G).Value2
                If Left(strng, 3) = "col" Then
                    If IsNumeric(Mid(strng, 4, 1)) Then
                        col = CLng(Mid(strng, 4, 1))
                        If col <= 5 Then CWS.Cells(k, G).Value = colArray(col - 1)
                    End If
                End If
            Next G
'        Next j
    End With
End Sub
```

but there's plenty of thing you should explain (`ThisBook`, `CWS`, `With Range(Cells(k, j * 4 + 2), Cells(k + 1, j * 4 + 4))` )to make a sense of it!

Comment: @durba138: did you get through it?